# Is there any Social Translation web site?

Tags: webapp-rec, collaboration, translation

Is there any web app that people can translate texts (articles, movie subtitles, etc) together?

Comment: the title is somewhat misleading ...

Comment: @akira how do you suggest to change title?

Comment: your first sentence of the question-body looks good for me. the title made me think of "translation to social related stuff", not "work together on one translation"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://mygengo.com/string/ Might fit the bill, depending on the type of data you need to translate. String is more Web development oriented, but  depening on exactly what you want to do, it could be useful

Comment: > *"String, our app for localization, is shutting down on August 30, 2013."*

Answer (score 4):

use any colloborative editor:

- any incarnation of http://etherpad.com/
- [googles translator toolkit](http://translate.google.com/toolkit/list?#translations/active) looks like a good start
- any instance of [bespin](http://mozillalabs.com/bespin/)
- [docs.google.com](http://docs.google.com)

Comment: I think he means more something like a site where other people collaborate and translate your text (in return you could translate something for someone else). What you suggest means you first have to search for people who want to translate with/for you.

Comment: Etherpad has [great plugins](https://static.etherpad.org/index.html) to expand towards effective collaborative translations but is highly recommended to host your own instance. Google Translator Toolkit* and *Bespin* are not working anymore. *Google Docs* have great features, but is too slow in caseof large content (my experience).

Answer (score 2):

There's a service called [Transifex](http://www.transifex.net/) that does the same thing for open source software projects. While it wouldn't work perfectly for an article, I don't see why it cannot be used.

I haven't used it extensively, even less in such a scenario, but it might be worth taking a look. A limitation is that it's for open source and public, which you might not want in all cases.

Comment: Sadly isn't working anymore.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be what you're looking for, but [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/#) actually lets you [suggest a better translation](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2007/03/suggest-better-translation.html) for anything you let it translate, which is kind of a "social feature". They use the gathered data to improve translation quality in future updates of the service.

Comment: look at the google-translator-toolkit i mentioned, that looks really like a collaborative editor for bigger translations.

Answer (score 1):

[Read this](http://www.marketwire.com/press-release/hi5-First-Major-Site-to-Launch-Language-Translation-Service-on-OpenSocial-v08-903786.htm) for a multi-lingual social networking site with a translation feature.

For movie subtitles see [OpenSubtitles.org](http://www.opensubtitles.org/en)

Comment: Was there that much advertising on the web site when you posted this answer?

Comment: @Andrew Unfortunately, yes... I have only used it for a few obscure titles with pretty good results (as long as you can navigate your way through the ads and popups).

Comment: The referred article doesn't exist anymore. And the [OpenSocial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSocial) platform last release was on *August 30, 2013*

Answer (score 1):

[Crowdin](https://crowdin.net) lets teams do translations in a social way, but it is more for software-related projects.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good post talking about the social translation project that TED is running to translate their videos into other languages.

http://www.ethanzuckerman.com/blog/2009/05/13/ted-embraces-social-translation/

One of the tools they refer to, CONYAC (conyac.cc), might be what you are looking for.

There are also several other good links on Ethan's blog if you read through it.

Comment: [TED Translators announced a launch on CaptionHub](https://tedtranslators.com/2021/07/07/ted-translators-launch-on-captionhub/) today. *"CaptionHub offers a user-friendly experience with an advanced suite of tools that allow users to create high-quality subtitles. Plus, it includes a number of features that translators have long requested"*

Answer (score 0):

Do you require any special tools for translation, or just basic text editing?

If basic collaborative text editing is sufficient, you can use [WebClipper](http://webklipper.com), which allows you to annotate any web page collaboratively.

Comment: There is no such service on the page anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Cucumis is a community of translators who share their linguistic knowledge and help each other online.

http://www.cucumis.org/

Comment: Looks like a great service, but the [webmaster's](https://www.cucumis.org/members_1_u/profile_p_2.html) last visit was on ‎*6 August 2019 11:48* and cannot register due to *"Unexpected error."*

Answer (score 0):

[Global Voices](http://globalvoicesonline.org/) seems to be a community built around translating blogs to and from other languages. I haven't tried it, but some of the people involved have been interviewed on [CBC's Spark](http://cbc.ca/spark).

Answer (score 0):

You can run your own app using:

Pootle - http://translate.sourceforge.net/wiki/. Some wordpress translations are beeing done using this tool.

Comment: Another one: GlotPress - http://blog.glotpress.org/ - it is used for translation of wordpress to czech language for example. For more information see also GlotPress Trac (look for the link on the right side).

Comment: Sadly doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try [www.wikitranslation.org](http://wikitranslation.org)
. You submit texts for translation and the online community can translate it for you.

Comment: Service unavailable and the domain is suspended.